# File not found exception while making fileinputstream?

Tags: java, jasper-reports, inputstream, filenotfoundexception, fileinputstream

I try to create a `fileInputStram` for Jasper i get `FileNotFoundException`.
my jasper file and the java class is under the same package.
i use java 1.8 and jasperreport 5.5.0

**Does anybody know what is the wrong in this code?**

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: de\reports\off\office.jasper (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at de.reports.off.PrintOffice.retrieveStream(PrintOffice.java:105)
```

this is my methode:

```
public static FileInputStream retrieveStream() {
        final String OFFICE_JASPER = "de\\reports\\off\\office.jasper";
        File jasperFile = new File( OFFICE_JASPER );
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream( jasperFile);
        }
        catch ( FileNotFoundException e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return fis;
    }
```

Comment: Maybe you are wrong in the path? Is that a relative or absolute path?

Comment: The system cannot find the path you have specified

Answer (score 1):

If you create a `File` object with a relative path, it will be relative the directory specified in `user.home` (normally the directory from which you start your application).

example:
- your application is started from directory `C:\dir1\app`
- the `File` will refer to the file `C:\dir1\app\de\reports\off\office.jasper`

Answer (score 0):

My IDE didn't copy the file when compiling.
It was just small adjustment in pom file where .jasper was defined.
i added `/src` to `<directory>${basedir}/src</directory>`

```
<resource>
                <directory>${basedir}/src</directory>
                <filtering>false</filtering>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.jasper</include>
                </includes>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>target</exclude>
                    <exclude>**/target</exclude>
                    <exclude>**/target/**</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
```